# Lumen Login tutorial for web app no API?

Tags: laravel, lumen, lumen-5.2

I'm using lumen to make a website. I choose it because it has been told that lumen is a stunningly fast php micro framework. I need login guide. I have created login form and received data, and validated them. Now I need to check user credinals and login user. Auth::attempt($usercredinals) is not working. Fatal error with method not found is thrown. Is there any idea to use middleware and create routes that automatically login user and make available through Auth::user() method.

Thanks in Advance.

I have not found full tutorial or documentation for authentication.

Comment: Lumen isn't an appropriate choice for building a traditonal web app. It's aimed pretty squarely at building API microservices. You should switch to Laravel for this use case.

Comment: Choosing a framework that doesn't include functionality you need on the basis of speed is a red herring. If the performance isn't good enough you can improve it by refactoring queries, caching responses, finding and resolving bottlenecks in the code and so on. If that's still not enough then putting something like Varnish in front of the server is worth considering.

Comment: Remember, developer time is an awful lot more expensive than server time these days, so as a general rule of thumb a framework that makes you more productive is better value for money.